# Access filepath of C# Console Application in Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, filepath, azure-webjobs

I have Folder under my C# Console project "~/Assets/Samle.xlsx". I want to access this excel file on local machine & On Azure WebJob. Plz Help

Comment: Doe the file have to be in the `Assets/` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your local side, if the file is under `~/Assets/Samle.xlsx`, make sure you have set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always** for your `Samle.xlsx` file, then you could use the following code for getting the file path:

```
string filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Assets\Samle.xlsx");
```

When published as Azure WebJob, it would under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\{job type}\{job name}` of your web app, you could use [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check it.Your webjob would be copied to a temp directory (e.g. `%TEMP%\jobs\{job type}\{job name}\{random name}`) by default for running, at this point your excel file would under the temp folder. For more details, you could refer to [WebJob Working Directory](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs).

By default, you are reading the excel file under temp folder. If you want to read excel file directly from the WebJob binaries directory, you could change the [WebJob Working Directory](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs) or you could use the `WEBROOT_PATH` environment variable which points to `d:\home\site\wwwroot`, then you could combine it with your path as follows:

```
var path = $@"{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBROOT_PATH")}\app_data\jobs\<job type>\<job name>\Assets\Samle.xlsx";
```

Moreover, for reading the excel file, you could use [NPOI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NPOI/2.3.0), [SpreadsheetLight](http://spreadsheetlight.com/sample-code/), [Aspose.Cells for .NET](https://github.com/aspose-cells/Aspose.Cells-for-.NET), etc. Additionally, you could store your resource(s) to [Azure Blob storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) as the central storage and you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs) for getting started with Azure Blob storage.